# Multiple Join with same table QueryDSL hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, querydsl

I'm facing a problem with QueryDSL 4.0.5 and multiple JOIN.
I've two class :

```
public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
}

public class Ranking {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer rank;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer point;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "seller_id")
    private Users user;
}
```

Some users are sellers and have ranks.

What I want to do is to get for each users, his id and name, and his rank at `2015-12-01 00:00:00` (which exist for sure due to my project) and his rank at `2015-12-01 00:00:00` (which could be null)
(date are for eg)

So in SQL (which work perfectly fine):

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, r.rank, r2.rank
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN ranking r ON u.id=r.seller_id AND r.date = '2015-12-01 00:00:00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ranking r2 ON u.id=r2.seller_id AND r2.date = '2015-10-28 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY r.rank
```

But when I want to do this request with queryDSL, It's not working...
Here my code:
I've two `QRanking` because of multiple join with same table)

```
private static final QSeller SELLER = QSeller.seller;
private static final QRanking RANKING = QRanking.ranking;
private static final QRanking RANKING_OLD = new QRanking("old");

queryFactory.from(SELLER)
.select(SELLER.id, SELLER.username, RANKING.point, RANKING.rank, RANKING_OLD.rank)
.innerJoin(RANKING.seller).on(RANKING.campaign.id.eq(campaignId).and(RANKING.date.eq(last)))
.leftJoin(RANKING_OLD.seller).on(RANKING_OLD.campaign.id.eq(campaignId).and(RANKINGY_OLD.date.eq(secondToLast)))
.orderBy(RANKING.rank.asc())
.fetch();
```

And here extract of logs:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'ranking.seller'

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'ranking.point'

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'ranking.rank'

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.InvalidPathException: Invalid path: 'old.rank'

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'ranking.seller'
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception tells you that `"ranking.seller"` is an invalid path. This path originates from `.innerJoin(RANKING.seller)`. Hibernate probably considers it invalid because you are dereferencing a path `"ranking"` that you have not defined in your query (it does not appear in the from clause, or any preceeding join clause). You'll probably want to write `.innerJoin(SELLER.ranking, RANKING)` instead.